# How to model several variables per product

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, php-7.2, php-7.3

I want to know the way to design database for product data (variation-variables data)

### Example

I have those tables:

Products: id - Title
Attributes: id - name
Options : id - name - attribute_id

Each product has one or more attributes, and each attributes has one or more options.

This is the setup I have in mind:

Table `product_attribute_option`:

ID - price - sale_price - qty - product_id - attribute_id - option_id

My question is how to manage this situation with a migration and a database?

Comment: Take a look at existing solutions and recreate them. They've proven (mostly) failproof. For instance Magento' EAP system. (Magento 1, I haven't looked at Magento 2 yet, don't know if they use something similar)

Comment: Have you take a look here: [Database: Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple DB solution for your app will be Opencart database schema

Take a look for their product structure
[image]